# GeoDjango support for Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, geodjango

From what I've been researching and testing, it seems SQL Server is not fully supported by GeoDjango. Is this correct?

Ive been running into errors such as "'DatabaseOperations' object has no attribute 'select'" only when I introduce a geometry data type field into the model.

Edit: Code for connecting Sql-Server to Django, using mssql-django version 1.3

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'mssql',
    'NAME': 'Planet-Django',
    'HOST': 'localhost',
    'OPTIONS': {
        'driver': 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server',
        'trusted_connection': 'yes',
    },
},
```

}

Comment: How did you try to connect with sql server? Kindly share the code snippet or relevant steps.

Comment: There are a few steps but it is possible https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6693/python-django-tutorial-website-sql-server-database/